# update field with aggregation and transaction- mongoDB and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, field, aggregation

I have an aggregation that takes a field- "updateAt" and convert it from string to date.

The aggregation code-

```js
const aggCurs = await collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      updateAt: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: `$updateAt`
        }
      },
    }
  },
  { $out: collection.collectionName }
]
```

The above aggregation works great, but now I need to wrap it inside a **transaction**.

The problem is that transaction supports aggregation excluding "$out" stage, as you can see here- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-operations/#crud-operations

So how can I write the aggregation pipeline results to a collection in transaction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your mongodb version

Comment: Hi, my version is-  3.6.2
@CharchitKapoor

Comment: Then, I am afraid we cannot do this operation in a transaction.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor
Do you have any suggestion to how to do it in other way with transaction?

Comment: There are only two ways as far as I know, either run without a transaction or fetch documents one by one, convert the date from string to a Date object in nodejs, and then run update command in a transaction.